# Forcing HTTPS to one directory - Removing WWW

Tags: .htaccess, http, https

I've got a slight problem, this is what i'm using to force https to the checkout directory, just a precaution but the problem is once you go back through to the main pages it inserts www into the URL.

This is a problem as the rest of the sight does not use a www, can anyone suggest how to addapt this to remove/ keep out the www

```
# force https for all URLs in /checkout
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^x9 https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# force http for all other URLs that are not in /checkout
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/x9
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

---

Edit

If you say it's not that section above. This problem only started after the above code was added though, Ive never had this problem before and the code below has been on my site for several months.

```
 #Take off index.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: This code is not forcing `www` into URL. Do you have some other .htaccess code/framework forcing this.

Comment: Ok obviously this new code is forcing `www` in all the URIs ending with `/index.html`. Do you want to remove www for all the URLs now, both http and https?

Comment: @anubhava It wasn't before, that's why I'm a little confused, but yes I want to remove www from all URL's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case keep your .htaccess like this:

```
#Take off index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%1 [R=301,L]

# force https for all URLs in /checkout
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^x9 https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# force http for all other URLs that are not in /checkout
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/x9
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```